# SQL Server : pivot on non aggregate field - employee hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a CTE (Common Table Expression) that returns employee hierarchy based on level 
but I need it in a single row with the hierarchy

```
Level    employeeNumber    employeeName    managernumber
0        1287               Me              789 
1        789                My Boss         345
2        345                His Boss        123
....
10       3                  bla             000
```

I need to display it as

```
Level0         Level1         Level2 ... Level10, EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName
Me             My Boss        His Boss            1287            Me
```

Can it be done with a pivot? seems like pivot need an aggregate function

this is the query,

```
SELECT  
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
FROM
(select [Level], EmployeeNumber,EmployeeName, ManagerNumber from dbo.GetEmployeeHierachy(MYID)) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Max(EmployeeName)
FOR [Level] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) AS PivotTable;
```

but it returns this

thanks , almost there now i'm getting this

```
0           1   2                .....
NULL    NULL    His Boss
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
ME        NULL  NULL
NULL    My Boss NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL   
....
```

Should be

ME          MY Boss        His Boss ....

Comment: Yes it can be done with pivot, since it is a string you will have to use `max` or `min` as the aggregate function

Comment: Take the`EmployeeName` out of the final select list since you are using it in the aggregate function.

Comment: You should only include the columns in the select list that are needed for the final pivot, in this case try removing the EmployeeNumber and ManagerNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my fault

I was using to many columns for grouping

```
SELECT  * FROM
(select [Level],EmployeeName from dbo.GetEmployeeHierachy(MYID)) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
Max(EmployeeName) FOR [Level] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) AS PivotTable;
```